# How to get xmlnodelist of OriginDestinationOptions which is having exact two OriginDestinationOption

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How to get `xmlnodelist` of `OriginDestinationOptions` which is having exact two `OriginDestinationOption`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <OTA_AirPriceRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
            <ns1:PricedItinerary ApplyMarkup="Y" FareType="Refundable" LFSPRICEDIFF="0" MatrixFare="" OriginDestinationRPH="DELBOMG8346G820160520BOMDELG8329G820160522" OriginDestinationRefNumber="2" ReturnOnly="true" SequenceNumber="" SupplierSystem="G8CP" isTBF="false">
                <ns1:AirItinerary FareType="Refundable" SupplierCode="G8CP" SupplierSystem="G8CP" TripType="" UniqueIdentifier="1">
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions WorkFlow="PFB">
                        <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
            </ns1:AirItinerary>
        </OTA_AirPriceRS>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I want to select all 'abc' node which is having two child node 'xyz' . occurrence of childnode is not more than two and not less than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath would be as follow :

```
//ns1:OriginDestinationOptions[count(ns1:OriginDestinationOption)=2]
```

Make sure to register the prefix `ns1` to an `XmlNamespaceManager` and don't forget to pass the namespace manager to `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` (whichever you use to execute the XPath).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. Issue resolved :-)